# Still problems with gazebo_ros and Urdf spawn

Tags: ros, spawn-model, gazebo-ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am still trying to get my gazebo and ros properly work together. But every time it fails because of urdf-spawning issues.
So what I am trying or tried is following:

- Install ROS-Indigo with `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-dekstop-full`
- Install Gazebo 2.2.2 from source (I tried a lot of branches already) as described [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install&ver=2.2&cat=get_started) (tried with SDF 1.4, 1.4.11, 1.5, 2.0) I am also aware of this [issue](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4633) but I can't find there the ultimate solution o.O
- Install Gazebo_ros_pkgs from debian (`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control`).

So every time (it doesnt matter if I try with hector or turtlebot or husky or smthelse) the spawn_model part of gazebo_ros will let my gazebo crash.

Am I missing something? Do I wont understand something? I know this question was asked a lot and i already found some 'solutions' but nothing helped me so far.

And it seems that not all people here have problems with this, can you explain me your procedure to install everything so it works?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193367/still-problems-with-gazebo_ros-and-urdf-spawn/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for the records:

It works now while installing gazebo and the gazebo_ros_pkgs as [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros) tutorial describes.

Specific use this command: `sudo apt-get install ros-$distro-gazebo-ros-pkgs-current` notice to exchange $distro with your current distribution.

---

Originally posted by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) with karma: 232 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2